# How to call cl-who:*http-stream* in common-lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Lisp newbie here. I have been referring to web-development in common lisp using `CL_WHO` package from [here](https://edicl.github.io/cl-who/). In the first line of code they are asking for a `*http-stream*`, can anybody explain me what it is and how one would call it?

Comment: Hello, nowadays I would advise to use Spinneret: https://github.com/ruricolist/spinneret (or a templating engine like Djula (https://github.com/mmontone/djula/) or Ten (by the same author).

Comment: Hi @Ehvince, these are html generators correct ? I want to do web-development , so maybe you have any other suggestions. I have tried so far AllegroServe and Hunchentoot

Comment: Correct. Here's a list of HTML generators: https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#html-generators-and-templates You will find s-exp ones (cl-who, Spinneret…), more regular ones (Djula, Django-like), and others mixing the two (Ten: like Djula, but allows to write Lisp freely in the template). Yes, I recommend Hunchentoot, possibly with easy-routes. See: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/web.html

Answer (score 1):

As it says at the beginning of the example:

> Let's assume that `*HTTP-STREAM*` is the stream your web application is supposed to write to.

So it's whatever stream you want to contain the resulting HTML. If you want to write to a file, use `with-open-file`, then provide the :

```
(with-open-file (my-html-file "filename.html" :direction :output)
  (with-html-output (my-html-file) 
    (:html (:body "Not much there"))
    (values)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error when I use *http-stream* elsewhere, saying its nil and is not of type stream. I am guessing the "filename.html" you mention is the Word document in Webpage format or maybe that's where I am wrong?

Comment: `filename.html` is the HTML file you want to create.

Comment: You can only use `http-stream` within the body of `with-open-file`, it's a local variable. This is a standard CL function you should already be familiar with.